# Why does the same code work or not for different lines?

Tags: go

```golang
muxMaps := http.NewServeMux()
muxMaps.HandleFunc("/", func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {w.Write([]byte("maps page"))})

mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.HandleFunc("/", func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {w.Write([]byte("main page"))})
mux.Handle("/maps/", http.StripPrefix("/maps", muxMaps))
mux.Handle("/maps1/", http.StripPrefix("/maps1", muxMaps))

http.ListenAndServe(":8000", mux)
```

Request "http://localhost:8000/" returns "main page"

Request "http://localhost:8000/maps1/" returns "maps page"

But the request "http://localhost:8000/maps/" redirects to "http://localhost:8000/" and returns "main page"

Ok, maybe the order matters. I try this:

```golang
mux.Handle("/maps1/", http.StripPrefix("/maps1", muxMaps))
mux.Handle("/maps/", http.StripPrefix("/maps", muxMaps))
```

And the result is unchanged.

Why is that? What's the magic for the word "maps"?

Comment: I can not reproduced the issue. I tested with `curl 'http://localhost:8000/maps/'` and got `maps page`.

Comment: @zeke-lu Thank you. Indeed, the query using curl returns the correct value. The problem occurs in a request using a browser :(

Comment: Please check the requests in the DevTools of the browser. You can copy a request as curl command, then test with curl directly. It's most likely that the URL is not `http://localhost:8000/maps/`.

Comment: @zeke-lu In the old version of Firefox, the request "http://localhost:8000/maps/" returns a 301 code. In the new version of Chromium, this request returns the correct value, like curl.

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue with Firefox 111.0.1. Can you copy the request as curl command or save as HAR and share?

Comment: Please note that a browser will cache a 301 response. Maybe that's why you saw the behavior on that specific browser. Try to disable the cache and test again.

Comment: @zeke-lu Thank you very much. The problem really was in the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem really was in the browser cache.